# Small question in a proof of completeness

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite dimensional normed spaces. Let $D:X \to Y$ An isometric isomorphism. If $X$ is complete then Y is also complete.

This is what I have got:

Let $\{y_n\}$ be Cauchy in Y. Then $D^{-1}(y_n)$ is Cauchy in X and since X is complete, it has a limit $x \in X.$

Then, $$D\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}D^{-1}(y_n)\right) = Dx \in Y$$ since D is onto. Thus, Y is complete.

I am wondering how do we know that $D^{-1}(y_n)$ is Cauchy??

Comment: So far, you haven't used the isometry property! The distance of $y_n$ to $y_k$ is the same as that of $D^{-1}(y_n)$ to $D^{-1}(y_k)$

Answer (score 1):

You know that $D^{-1}(y_n)$ is Cauchy because
$$
\|D^{-1}(y_n)-D^{-1}(y_m)\|_X=\|D^{-1}(y_n-y_m)\|_X=\|D(D^{-1}(y_n-y_m))\|_Y=\|y_n-y_m\|_Y,
$$
because $D$ is both an isometry and an isomorphism.

(You could also avoid the extra step of applying $D$ here if you realize that the inverse of an isometric isomorphism is also an isometric isomorphism.)

Comment: The general spirit of this answer looks correct, but your notation suggests that the metric space is derived from a norm on a vector space, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: The OP explicitly calls them "finite dimensional normed spaces".

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Not a necessary assumption for the problem though.

Comment: Clearly not.  But it IS the assumption given.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$(D^{-1}(y_n))_n$ is Cauchy because $D^{-1}$ is an isometry isomorphism, and thus the distances between $D^{-1}(y_m)$ and $D^{-1}(y_n)$ are the same as the distances between $y_m$ and $y_n$, and $(y_n)_n$ is Cauchy by assumption.

Answer (score 0):

General fact: if $f$ is uniformly continuous between metric spaces, then it maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences. This is indeed the case if $f$ is linear and continuous.